# Install Opengeo 3.0.1 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu, boundless-suite

I tried to install OpenGeo community edition 3.0.1 in Ubuntu 12.04. In the installation instruction it is mentioned that this version is supported only "10.04 and above"(http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/ubuntu/suite.html). But except the 10.04 there is no other version available in apt (http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu/dists/).

So is there any way to install OpenGeo 3 in Ubuntu 12.04 or later versions?

Answer (score 3):

The installation goes well on Ubuntu 12.04. In fact I used the same instructions a month ago to install OpenGeo on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: now i tried to install in ubuntu 12.10 and it show an error for `libgdal` package

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-9.0 postgresql-client-9.1
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install opengeo
```

You may also need to remove postgis 1.5