# Installing OpenGeo Suite on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux, boundless-suite

I originally posted this as [Install Opengeo 3.0.1 in ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58730), but I thought it would be best to ask a new question .  If I should have simply posted on the other forum, my apologies.

I am also having issues installing OG on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run:

```
apt-get install opengeo
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
opengeo : Depends: opengeo-server (>= 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is my first time using Linux.

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get install opengeo-server" and see if the broken package can be fixed.

Comment: Running your suggestion now is stating that opengeo-server depends on opengeo-tomcat6.  I am running tomcat7.  Do I need to remove tc7 and install tc6?

Comment: Now you are getting beyond my expertise. If nothing else depends on Tc7 it wouldn't hurt to try. Or "sudo apt-get remove opengeo" this might remove 7 if it is not needed by other programs.

Comment: I am getting around this by installing the individual components of OpenGeo one-at-a-time.  Slowly but surely I'll get this all figured out.  Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: @evv_gis If you could provide the output of apt-get install opengeo-server it would be helpful to know exactly why the package won't install. As for your workaround of installing the packages you want and deploy them in your version of tomcat, that is indeed what I would suggest.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Tomcat7. Anybody had any success? Thanks!

Comment: @WillWhite I was able to install the individual components of OpenGeo one at a time.  I also (and probably obviously) needed to restart the VM after each component finished installing.

Comment: This is apparently still an issue today ... can't install OpenGeo suite on ubuntu 12.04 with tomcat7. @evv_gis, are there instructions somewhere on how to install each component individually, or has a better answer become available?